# How can I access path variables in a URI template in the view (Spring 3/SpringMVC)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a URI template in the form of "/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}", and can access the path variables in the controller via @PathVariable, but when building links in the view I need a reference to the different path variables.

As an example, let's say the user requests "/hotels/123/bookings/booking-123", and in the view, there is a need to link back to the bookings listing "/hotels/123/bookings/".  How do I get a hook to {hotel} from the URI template to generate the link?  It seems clunky to inject this into each view, is there a simpler way that I am missing?

Comment: If it as simple as linking to the upper level then why not just use relative urls like "../"?

Comment: You'll just have to live with the clunkiness for now. I suggest, however, that you submit a feature request to http://jira.springsource.org.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been raised as a [feature](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6486) in Spring.